# how can we get online user to gmail chat?

Tags: android

i am developing gmail chat application in android...anybody know how can we get the online user?
i would login from my gmail id...i want to show  the my friends who is online from chat list...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

This section of the API looks like a good starting point.